# How to find documents that contain a certain number of Embedded/Nested Documents in an array

Tags: mongodb

I was wondering if it is possible to select documents based on the number of nested documents in an array?

For example could my query select the URL of any document that contains less than or equal to 2 nested documents in `sections` that have `type: paragraph`? In the docs below I would expect that to return the first object but not the second.

```
{ 
   "_id":ObjectId(   "5e2aafb6143f79b18d27bf7a"   ),
   "metadata":{ 
      "language":"en-gb",
      "timestamp":1517225687000,
      "url": "foo.com"
   },
   "body":{ 
      "sections":[ 
         { 
            "href":"http://test.co.uk/test.png",
            "type":"image"
         },
         { 
            "text":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
            "type":"paragraph"
         },
         { 
            "text":"consectetur adipiscing elit",
            "type":"paragraph"
         }
      ]
   }
}

{ 
   "_id":ObjectId(   "5e2aafd8143f79b18d27bf7b"   ),
   "metadata":{ 
      "language":"en-gb",
      "timestamp":1517225687000,
      "url": "bar.com"
   },
   "body":{ 
      "sections":[ 
         { 
            "href":"http://test.co.uk/test.png",
            "type":"image"
         },
         { 
            "text":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
            "type":"paragraph"
         },
         { 
            "text":"consectetur adipiscing elit",
            "type":"paragraph"
         },
         { 
            "text":"Integer ut ligula diam",
            "type":"paragraph"
         }
      ]
   }
```

I have read the Query Documents section of the tutorial on the MongoDB site but couldn't figure out how I might put something like that together.

Comment: You can use the [$size aggregation operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/index.html) to check if an array has `n` or more elements. And, you can _project_ the required field using a suitable syntax from this: [Project Fields to Return from Query](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/).

Comment: Thank you @prasad_, I'll give that a go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the result you expect by using a mix of `$expr`, `$lte`, `$size` & `$filter`, by using this aggregation and without the need to create a new field:

```js
db.your_collection_name.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "$expr": {
                "$lte": [
                    {
                        // get the size of the filtered array
                        "$size": {
                            // filter sections of type paragraph
                            "$filter": {
                                "input": "$body.sections",
                                "as": "section",
                                "cond": {
                                    "$eq": ["$$section.type", "paragraph"]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    2
                ]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

> the result will looks like:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5e2aafb6143f79b18d27bf7a",
    "body": {
      "sections": [
        {
          "href": "http://test.co.uk/test.png",
          "type": "image"
        },
        {
          "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
          "type": "paragraph"
        },
        {
          "text": "consectetur adipiscing elit",
          "type": "paragraph"
        }
      ]
    },
    "metadata": {
      "language": "en-gb",
      "timestamp": 1.517225687e+12,
      "url": "foo.com"
    }
  }
]
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PCObGSriASc)